# Place a website on Wordpress on a subdomain

Tags: domain

Can I host a domain (website.com ) on a third-party server (NS-Getcourse servers), and a subdomain (sub.website.com ) on Wordpress?

Is it possible to do this by adding a CNAME record?

Comment: I'm assuming you're meaning the other way around: that you can install WordPress on a subdomain (unless you're talking about wordpress.com). In that case, yes, absolutely. All WordPress is is a collection of files and databases you can add to any website. You'd have to have root file access and/or FTP access but is absolutely doable.

Comment: That being said, the question doesn't have anything to do with WordPress specifically (just happens to--but could be anything else), so the question is [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this StackExchange. I'd recommend going to the [Webmasters StackExchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) for more specific help.